# Chemical equilibrium for a $2-2$ scattering and Boltzmann equation in cosmology and astroparticle physics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology, dark-matter, baryogenesis, leptogenesis

**Definition of chemical equilibrium** According to the definition of chemical equilibrium in Wikipedia, it is a situation where the *rate of the forward reaction is same as the rate of backward reaction* and the *concentrations of the reactants and the products do not change with time*. I hope that the same definition applies to particle physics processes such as a 2-2 scattering of the form $A+B\leftrightarrow C+D$ i.e., in chemical equilibrium concentrations or number densities of each particle species remains unchanged with time.

**Consistency of the definition with Boltzmann equation** Boltzmann equation is used to study baryogenesis, relic abundance of dark matter and so on. According to Boltzmann equation, the number density $n$ of the species $A$ in an expanding Universe changes as: $$\frac{dn}{dt}+3Hn=\int d\pi_A d\pi_B d\pi_C d\pi_D[f_Af_B|\mathcal{M}|^2_{AB\to CD}+f_Cf_D|\mathcal{M}|^2_{CD\to AB}]$$ where $\mathcal{M}_{AB\to CD}$ and $\mathcal{M}_{CD\to AB}$ are the amplitudes of the forward and backward processes respectively, $H$ is the Hubble parameter defined as $H=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$ where $a$ is the exapsnion factor. $d\pi_i$ and $f_i$ ($i=A,B,C,D$) are respectively the integrals over phase space and phase space distributions. Due to the $+$ sign on the RHS, the RHS is nonzero in chemical equilibrium even when $$\mathcal{M}_{AB\to CD}=\mathcal{M}_{CD\to AB},~\text{(assuming CP or T invariance)}$$ Therefore, $$\frac{dn}{dt}+3Hn\neq 0.$$ Therefore, the number density of species $A$ can change with time even when the dilution due to expansion is zero i.e., $H=0$. Therefore, the number density or the concentration of $A$ changes in even in chemical equilibrium.

**Question** Shouldn't the RHS of the Boltzmann equation be zero in chemical equilibrium in order to keep the concentration of each species unchanged with time?

Comment: I don't really understand the question - by definition, in a chemical equilibrium you would have $\mathrm{d}n/\mathrm{d}t = 0$. You exhibit an equation where $\mathrm{d}n/\mathrm{d}t \neq 0$, therefore it describes a system that is not in chemical equilibrium. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Let me say it differently. If $dn/dt=0$ with $H=0$ (assuming no expansion), the RHS must be zero. But the RHS cannot be zero. Chemical equilibrium only requires $\mathcal{M}_{AB\to CD}=\mathcal{M}_{CD\to AB}$. The RHS is zero only in absence of scattering in which case the number density dilutes as $n\propto a^{-3}$  (if $H\neq 0$) due to expansion or stays constant in absence of expansion (when $H=0$).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Do you mean Boltzmann equation cannot describe chemical equilibrium?

Comment: The signs in your Boltzmann equation look wrong. Surely, the “in” and “out” rates have opposite sign

Comment: Thanks. What about $(f^{\rm eq}_Af^{\rm eq}_B-f^{\rm eq}_Cf^{\rm eq}_D)?$ Will it vanish? @Thomas

Comment: Yes, that’s detailed balance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first term on the right hand side should have a minus sign because the process $A+B \rightarrow C +D$ depletes the species $A$. So if all the $f$'s have their equilibrium form, $dn/dt$ should be zero.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the sign mistake. What about $(f^{\rm eq}_Af^{\rm eq}_B-f^{\rm eq}_Cf^{\rm eq}_D)?$ How will it vanish? @EricDavidKramer

Comment: For the simplest example, suppose the chemical potential is zero and take the statistics to be Maxwell-Boltzmann (you are already assuming that in your Boltzmann equation by not including $1-f$ and $1+f$ factors for FD or BE). Then in equilibrium, $f_A = e^{-E_A/T}$ and similarly for the other species. The products are equal because $E_A + E_B = E_C + E_D$ by energy conservation.